# While writting unittests for a function, should I mock the internal function calls made?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

```
struct api {
   void do_yo() {
      a = func1();
      if (a) dosomething();
      func2();
      dosomething2();
   }
};
```

Now I am writing unittests for `do_yo`, so should I mock `func1` and `func2`?

Or just test the observable effects of `do_yo`?

Comment: are `func1` and `func2` part of your unit?

Comment: @codekaizer Yes, they are part of the same class `api`. They may or may not be overriden by the user who will make a derived class of `api`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to mock `func1()` and `func2()` to see how `do_yo()` reacts on different random behaviors from them.

Preferably since `func1()` has the most impact to `do_yo()` you need to define the possible values of `a` that will make `do_yo()` fail or successful.

At the end of the day, the purpose of unit test is to eliminate undefined or sporadic behavior based on a set of some unknown inputs. (i.e. have a higher percentage of code coverage).

---

**UPDATE**

In the event that a function is dependent on *external* factors, it's challenging to mock all possible behaviors and would *certainly* take time. Thus, we have a saying that goes: "whatever you can control and what makes sense, mock them".

Comment: Wouldn't testing `do_yo` also automatically test and include coverage for `func1` and `func2` ?

Comment: as much as possible, do unit test per function and remember [black box](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/362746/what-is-black-box-unit-testing). let's say `func1` and `func2` aren't part of your unit. so goes to say, `do_yo()` only cares about the output of `func1` which you can mock.

Comment: +1 as you mention undefined behaviour. My immediate thought is whether those functions are re-entrant, do they rely on or influence data that isn't visible here?

Comment: @ChrisBD, for re-entrancy, that will be more on integration testing. for me unit test's sole purpose is to define as much as possible the output of a function based on what goes in. It doesn't mind how many times it is called. Like the famous formula: *y = f(x)*. Unit tests is to know y based on a given x as much as possible.

Comment: @codekaizer, true, but in the example given there isn't any data passed to any of the functions, which leads me to believe that they are dependent on or determine external factors. As such mocking wouldn't be worth the effort, except as you pointed out maybe for func1 and testing here would be an integration test.

Comment: @ChrisBD, I certainly agree for external factors. These factors are too broad and it's really challenging to model such behaviors and mocking would be difficult. Updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

This is really more of a conceptual question.

The simple answer is: *mocking* should be seen as a last resort. You only use it if you have to. Meaning: there is no other way to sufficiently test your code under test without using mocks.

Thus: *when* you are able to write good unit tests for `do_yo()` without using mocks, then go for that. But if you really need to control such internal method calls, then you probably can't get around mocking them.

This is really about balancing different requirements / practices.

Comment: My worry here is that if I start mocking functions like `func1` and `func2` which are public (hence overridable by the user), the code structure of `do_yo` will become rigid to any more changes.

Comment: That is one of the reasons to be really careful about such mockings. You actually start testing implementation details here, exactly leading to making it harder to change code later on.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell as there isn't enough information on `func1` and `func2`, but if they're public as you've said, then I would mock them.

If they're public then you should have unit tests for them as well, regardless of testing `do_yo`, so you can attest that their logic is as you expect it to be.

(Think of it as a test-run for a restaurant: If you tested that the cooks can prepare the meals to meet your expectations, and now you want to test the waiters taking the meals from the kitchen, all you need is a response from the kitchen staff "the meal is ready" or any other response you might expect and not a real meal.)

And as some have mentioned, if `func1` and `func2` are hitting some externals then this becomes an integration test by not to mocking them.